# Recursive function to check all pairs in an array

Tags: c++, recursion

an int vector is given, and I need to find the maximum sum of number sequences that are more than 3 positions away from each other. So an example:

```
Input: 10, 5, 6, 7, 16, 18, 12
Output: 29
Explanation:
candidate "routes":
 10-7-12 = 29
 10-16   = 26
 10-18   = 28
 5-16    = 21
 5-18    = 23
 5-12    = 17
...
 16
 18
 12
```

I want to solve this problem using recursion and I have gotten to the point where the program tests all paths with numbers that are more than 3 positions away. However, it fails to test all the paths starting from the same digit.
Here my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int n = 7;
int sum = 0;
int temp=0;

void rec(int (*arr), int ind){
    if (ind > n-3){
        if(temp > sum)
        sum = temp;
        temp=0; 
        return;
}
    temp += arr[ind];
    
    cout<<arr[ind]<<" ";
    for(int i=3;i<n;i++)
    rec(arr, ind+i);

    cout<<endl;
}
int main(){
    int arr[n] = {10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 7};
    
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    rec(arr, i);

    cout<<endl<<endl<<"Max: "<<sum;
    return 0;}
```

Output:

```
10 9 7
8
8
7
9 8
8
7
9 8
7
9 7
8
8
7
Max: 26
```

Even though in this case the output is correct, you can see that it tests only 10-9-7 and not the other 10-8, 10-8 and 10-7. It seems it doesn´t even go in the first for-loop I called the function recursively.

Am I understanding something wrong or how do I accomplish that it tests all pairs that are more than 3 positions away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 problems here:

---

Based on your output:

```
10 9 7
8
8
⋮
```

Your code actually loops through all the possible routes. Instead of thinking your second line `8` and third line `8` as two complete routes, they were actually derived from your first rout `10 9 7`. So really think of it like this:

```
10 --- 9 --- 7
    `- 8
    `- 8
    `- 7
 9 --- 8
    `- 8
    `- 7
 ⋮
```

---

That's actually not your output. Plugged your code in, I got my output:

```
10 9 
8 
9 8 
9 
9 
8 


Max: 19
```

The reason that it didn't go through all routes is because your line:

```
if (ind > n-3)
{
      ⋮
    return;
}
```

You are terminating your loop way too early. Instead, you should only end it right before it goes out of index. So it should be:

```
if (ind > n - 1)
{
    ⋮
}
```

---

Your logic actually has flaws.

Because you always set your `temp` back to 0 once reached the last possible number inside the array, you actually lost some part of your previous sums. You can easily create a sequence that makes it fails, such as: `10, 9, 9, 7, 8, 20, 7`.

Instead of having `temp` as a global, it would be better to set it local, and being passed to each recursions.

To do that, you would need to add the `temp` as a parameter of your `rec` function, and call it like:

```
void rec(int (*arr), int ind, int temp)
{
    ⋮
    rec(arr, i, temp);
    ⋮
}


int main()
{
    ⋮
    rec(arr, i, 0);
    ⋮
}
```

Or if you want to keep the signature the same in your `main`, you could also add a default argument in your `rec`:

```
void rec(int (*arr), int ind, int temp = 0)
```

---

Side note, I would considering using `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of c-style array, to avoid having a global size `n` or passing `int (*arr)` in your function. Plus you can easily make your `arr` as a longer sequence.